# why "Serial1.available() >0" is executed several times?

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, serial-port, android-bluetooth

I'm just running some testing code to check serial communication in arduino with bluetooth device. So I write this test code:

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial1.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
if(Serial1.available()>0){
      Serial.println("magi interrupt");
      delay(1000);
  Serial1.end();
  Serial1.begin(9600);
 }
```

So as far I understand , if I send data through bluetooth device then if condition will be executed and then Serial1.end() disable this serial communication.after that , when Serial1.begin(9600) is executed, then Serial1 is setup again.

Shouldn't be Serail1.available() is not greater then zero anymore as long as I do not send any data ?

But when I execute this code , if condition is executed multiple times though I send data(2 or 3 digit data) only once. Why this happens? Why only several times ?

[image]

if I ignore " Serial1.end();  Serial1.begin(9600);  " then if condition start to executed in infinite loop after I send any message. Why is that??

Comment: From what I can see in the core code and assume from the long delay, this shouldn't be happening, however: Instead of running `end()` & `begin()` try clearing the actual RX data and see if the same problem persists: `while(Serial1.read() != -1);`  Is there a reason why you are starting and stopping Serial1?

Comment: actually I tried Serial1.flush() , but it doesn't help. If statement start executed in infinite loop after I send any data.

Comment: flush only clears the TX buffer, the loop I posted will clear the RX buffer. Also try printing the data on serial1 through serial so you can see if the data is changing or replicated.